# render checkbox and update data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm stuck changing the array of object value of checkbox. I'm even not sure my current approach is correct or not, because I have no clue what to do next. Assume fruits data is an ajax call, it's should come from componentWillMount right? should I set the state like `this.setState({input:ajaxresponse})`? I'm lost, it's hard for me because I was using jquery. Just now I also read about redux, I heard people said in redux you don't use setState, omg I'm lost.

http://jsbin.com/dodanahani/1/edit

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      input: {}
    }
  }

  handleChange(e,key){
    console.log(e.target.checked)
    // how to update state here? 
  }

  render() {
    const data = {
      "fruits":[
        {"name":"banana","value":true},
        {"name":"watermelon","value":false},
        {"name":"lemon","value":true},
      ]
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {data.fruits.map(obj => 
           <div key={obj.name}>
           <label>{obj.name}</label>
           <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, obj.name)} type="checkbox" defaultChecked={obj.value} />
            </div>
         )}
         <p>{this.state.fruits}</p>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is simple : user get api data, and he know his previously saved data, bind to view (checkboxes), and he can update them again. I'm stuck at sending back the changes.

Comment: http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/ Please read this. Also, don't read about redux until you're familiar with every reactjs concept; redux is good when you want to decouple state from your components or when you need global app state. https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367#.9zu89cdv2 <---- this is a good article about redux.

Comment: You should use redux to change state of your application, some global data. Who said you can't change state of your component with setState?